# Which method to use when you want to check the button is present or not during Karate UI autoamtion

Tags: user-interface, ui-automation, karate

Im confused about which method to use that gives result about if there is button present or not using karate ui automation. Im confused between using exists() and optional(). Can anyone help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#optional

If all you need to do is check if a button exists, use `exists()` like this:

```
* def flag = exists('#myButton')
# now you can use the value of flag to perform logic
```

Ask a new question with specifics if needed.

Comment: Thankyou so much !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Above provided code in not working, my test-cases are being passed when there is no button.

Comment: @NibeshRaut follow this process - or you are welcome to look for another framework: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test